# Android separate S3 and S4 layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

i have been trying to make separates folder layouts for the S3 and the s4,

I would like to separate layouts for S3 and S4.
i already tried sw360dp, but looks like both of them work from this density, 
any ideas how i can do it ?

Comment: Did you check with xhdpi and xxhdpi?

Comment: Since those phones have a very similar form factor, why are you trying to have a difference in the way your UI is laid out?

Comment: the main reason i'm trying to do this is because i'm working with a spinner wich size is so big in the S4 even with a 5sp size, but looks okay in the S3, so i wanted to get the DP for the S4 to make a dimens file

Answer (score 0):

All you need to know about screen sizes and density is on [Android Developers website here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

I would like to say, as I understand, never go for device specific layout designs unless you have to run your application only on a particular design. Google has created Android to run on a vast range of devices by various manufacturers. And the measure of density, as they have taken, is the measure you should take into account while designing layouts to better fit the devices with any screen size or any device from different manufacturers.